# how to combine elements from two text files and put them in a third file in java

Tags: java

I have two files Persons.txt and Hobby.txt.In the third file i want to put all the persons names and add each name some hobbies.i read the names from the persons file but i don't know how to add each persons different hobbies.

Comment: How to choose the hobbies to associate to each name?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: this is a homework.i have created a person.java class for the get and set methods fo the persons id;name;date;job and then i created the readfile.java

Comment: public void readFile(){
        Persoana p = new Persoana();
        try{
            while(input.hasNext()){

        String[] values = input.next().split(";");
               
                p.setId(values[0]) ;
                p.setNume(values[1]);
                p.setPrenume(values[2]);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 4; i++){
                    System.out.println(p.getNume() + " " + p.getPrenume());
                }
            }
        }

Comment: my third file should look like this:Ion Pop : baschet, volei 
Ilie Stan: steaua, handbal

Answer (score 3):

As a starter think about it this way.

Read the persons.txt then read the hobby.txt -- you know how to

Create a list of strings - How you want the third file to look like.

```
List<String> stringToWriteList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

add to the list the strings -- You probably want to loop the person.txt file for each person, then you need to define how you want to get the hoppy -- maybe randomly?

```
stringToWrite.add(person1 +", "+ hoppy1);  // Depends on the hobby logic
```

Then just write the list of strings to the file

```
try {
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));

  for(String line : stringToWriteList ){
    out.write(line);
    out.newLine();
  }
  out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Exception ");     
}
```

There are more technical ways to accomplish this, but the idea from this example is to new comers pick up one or two new things on how to write to a file -- easier to read\understand.

Comment: thanks for the answer.each person is written like this:id;name;birth_date;job and each hobby is like this:id;name;description